# passing GA4 event parameters with multiple values

Tags: google-analytics-4

In Analytics 4, how do I pass an event parameter that has more than one value (or can this be done at all)?

When I try passing an array:

```js
gtag('event', 'page_details', {
  'author': [ 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe' ],
});
```

I saw it pops out in the realtime report with value `John Doe,Jane Doe`.  I can't tell if it's reporting that multiple separate variables were recorded or if it just changed the name of the value to a single combined string.

Would multiple pushes maybe keep all that data?

```js
gtag('event', 'page_details', {
  'author': 'John Doe'
});
gtag('event', 'page_details', {
  'author': 'Jane Doe',
});
```